# Does $D$, and $\nabla$ mean partial or standard derivative for a vector valued function?

Tags: notation, vector-analysis

I'm reading a book where the symbol $D$ is used for vector differentiation. The problem is, I can't find out if $D_x$ is the total derivative or the partial derivative. Specifically, in the following formula:

$$D_xf(x,y(x))$$
I can interpret this in two ways
$$\begin{align}
&1. \quad D_xf(x,z)|_{z=y(x)}& \\
&2. \quad D_xg(x)&\text { where } g(x)=f(x,y(x))
\end{align}$$

**Which of these two interpretations is correct? Is there a generally accepted convention for that?** Also, where does $\nabla$ fit in?
i.e. is there a generally accepted interpretation of the respective meanings of the following two expressions?
$$\begin{align}\nabla_xf(x,y(x))\\
D_xf(x,y(x))
\end{align}$$

Comment: It should be the partial with respect to $x$

Comment: There is no convention, writing $D_x f(x,y(x))$ is ambiguous, but the context can make the interpretation clear.